# Why is DbContext for EF 5.0 Code-First entity not including read only properties in metadata?

Tags: entity-framework, knockout.js, entity-framework-5, knockout-2.0, breeze

I am working on Single Page Application using

```
.NET 4.5
Entity Framework 5.0
Knockout 2.2.1
BreezeJS 1.2.5
DurandalJS (Latest Version)
```

I have a POCO (mapped in EF-5 via Code-First) which includes a street address having the following fields

```
StreetAddress1 
StreetAddress2 
City 
State 
PostalCode
```

To help facilitate rendering of this information on the client, I created a read-only property called **DisplayAddress** with a *getter* which combines all of these fields together and appropriately deals with punctuation, spacing, and any missing items.

When Breeze pulls the entity, the data for the DisplayAddress property exists in the returned JSON. However, when Knockout tries to map the DisplayAddress, the system generates the following error.

```
Unable to parse bindings.↵Message: ReferenceError: DisplayAddress is not defined;↵Bindings value: text: DisplayAddress
```

Knockout does not seem to have DisplayAddress as a property on its object.

*Does anyone have any idea why Knockout/Breeze aren't seeing this property?*

Btw, here is the client JavaScript, and the returned JSON.

```
define(function (require) {
    var app = require('durandal/app');
    var system = require('durandal/system');

    // Added Company constructor to try and extend breeze entity with display address
    var Company = function () {
        this.DisplayAddress = ko.observable("");
    };

    // service name is route to the Web API controller
    var serviceName = 'api/CompanyList';

    // manager is the service gateway and cache holder
    var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
    var store = manager.metadataStore;

    store.registerEntityTypeCtor("Company", Company);

    // define the viewmodel
    var vm = {
        companys: ko.observableArray(),
        save: saveChanges,
        show: ko.observable(false),

        activate: function () {
            return getCompanys();
        }

    };

    // Fetch companies
    getCompanys;

    //#region private functions

    // get companies asynchronously
    // returning a promise to wait for     
    function getCompanys() {

        //logger.info("querying Todos");
        system.log("querying Companys");
        toastr.info("querying Companys");

        var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Companys");

        return manager
            .executeQuery(query)
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);

        // reload vm.companys with the results 
        function querySucceeded(data) {
            system.log("queried Companys");
            toastr.success("queried Companys");
            debugger;
            vm.companys(data.results);
            vm.show(true); // show the view
        }
    };

    function queryFailed(error) {
        //logger.error("Query failed: " + error.message);
        system.log("Query failed: " + error.message);
        toastr.error("Query failed: " + error.message);
    }

    function saveChanges() {
        return manager.saveChanges()
            .then(function () {
                system.log("changes saved");
                toastr.success("changes saved");
            })
            .fail(saveFailed);
    }

    function saveFailed(error) {
        system.log("Save failed: " + error.message);
        toastr.error("Save failed: " + error.message);
    }

    return vm;

    //#endregion
});
```

And the JSON

```
[
   {
      "$id":"1",
      "$type":"USWebDesigners.Data.Entities.Company, USWebDesigners.Data",
      "CompanyId":1,
      "CompanyName":"Happy Catfish",
      "Phone":"601-787-2528",
      "CompanyEmail":"howdy@happycatfish.com",
      "StreetAddress":"72 Technology Blvd",
      "City":"Ellisville",
      "State":"MS",
      "PostalCode":"39437",
      "CompanyUrl":"http://happycatfish.com",
      "PortfolioUrl":"http://happycatfish.com/our-work",
      "Services":[

      ],
      "SocialLinks":[

      ],
      "PortfolioItems":[

      ],
      "IsLeadParticipant":false,
      "IsActive":false,
      "CompanyStatus":0,
      "SiteQuality":0,
      "AverageRating":0.0,
      "DisplayAddress":"72 Technology Blvd<br />Ellisville, MS 39437",
      "CreatedOn":"2013-03-21T20:10:28.353"
   },
   {
      "$id":"2",
      "$type":"USWebDesigners.Data.Entities.Company, USWebDesigners.Data",
      "CompanyId":2,
      "CompanyName":"Creative Project Solutions, LLC",
      "StreetAddress":"170 Pine Grove Rd",
      "City":"Heidelberg",
      "State":"MS",
      "PostalCode":"39439",
      "Services":[

      ],
      "SocialLinks":[

      ],
      "PortfolioItems":[

      ],
      "IsLeadParticipant":false,
      "IsActive":false,
      "CompanyStatus":0,
      "SiteQuality":0,
      "AverageRating":0.0,
      "DisplayAddress":"170 Pine Grove Rd<br />Heidelberg, MS 39439",
      "CreatedOn":"2013-03-21T20:10:28.360"
   }
]
```

Of course, I did read through [Extending Breeze Entities](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities)  but have not quite gotten it to work.

**UPDATE**

I discovered that the DisplayAddress does not exist in the Metadata that Breeze is bringing back to the client. So, I guess the first question is why is an unmapped property not included in the metadata if it is a valid property on my POCO?

**UPDATE 2**

After doing further research, it appears that the read only property is not making its way into the DBContext metadata on the server. The new question becomes:

*Is it possible to override the metadata for a DBContext to add in the read only property?*

(Why would I want to do this? Because I want for Breeze to be able to bind to the read only property for display purposes.)

*If adding a read only property to the DBContext metadata is not possible, what is the best solution for adding this property on the client?*

Comment: post your js code and json that you get from the server

Comment: If you would be able to have that property in context's metadata you would also need column in the database because context's metadata describes mapping between class and database. Any framework building on top of these metadata introduces quite big dependency on what properties are in the database and what are not. Anyway context cannot map read-only properties => they cannot be in metadata.

Comment: Yes Ladislav. I understand that context does not generally map read-only properties. However, I am wondering if that metadata can somehow be extended to allow it. Frameworks like Upshot and Breeze use the context metadata as their template for the entity. However, in many cases it is very useful to have additional derived properties. Of course, some of these should be made available to the client. If DbContext cannot be extended, then perhaps it is useful for frameworks like Breeze to wrap the DbContext metadata with a layer that includes additional information.

Comment: If you don't need the computed column server-side, just create the string in the javascript code with a javascript method.  This will also reduce the amount of data returned from the server.

Comment: How do you mean @Moho?

Comment: You can take the logic in the Property accessor that builds the string and put it in a javascript functions to do the same thing client-side.

Comment: @Moho, Ah yes. This is actually what I did to "solve" the problem. However, it is actually not an optimal solution. JavaScript is more trouble to debug than .NET. Also, there are times when I may not want to expose the logic to the client. I see the inability to pass derived properties as a deficiency in Breeze that someone might want to look into.